# Insert each string values to table SQL using flask

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, flask

I have string value like:

```
test.test.com
atest.com
btest.com
ctest.com
```

I want to insert them into Database table like:
[DB Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCwxl.png)

I tried this:

```
@flask.route('/domain_settings', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def domain_settings():
   ss = (s.replace(' ', ''))
   print(ss)
   # test.test.com
   # atest.com
   # btest.com
   # ctest.com
   cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
   cur.execute('INSERT INTO domain (domain_name) VALUES (%s)', [ss])
   mysql.connection.commit()
   cur.close()
```

But it insert them into one row like:
[db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXhnI.png)

How can i achieve that?

Comment: if that is a single string value and you are using a single insert statement, then isn't the inserted value correct ?

Comment: if you want to insert each line as a row, you should split into different elements, then either do a batch insert or loop overt the split list and insert them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try split method and split the string on "\n" and then insert the values in a for loop.

```
@flask.route('/domain_settings', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def domain_settings():
   s_list = s.split('\n') 
   cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
   for domain in s_list:
       cur.execute('INSERT INTO domain (domain_name) VALUES (%s)', [domain])
   mysql.connection.commit()
   cur.close()
```